# Postgres error relation "new" does not exist on insert trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below trigger executes with out any error, but throws

```
ERROR:  relation "new" does not exist
```

on inserting single row into tbl1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_tbl1() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
    $BODY$ DECLARE
DECLARE no_of_rows INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) as no_of_rows FROM NEW; --error location
         ...
         ...
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
;
END; 
 $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER update_tbl2 AFTER INSERT ON tbl1
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_tbl1();
```

I am unable refer INSERTED, DELETED (SQL SERVER) rows in postgres using NEW and OLD, I appreciate any help.

I need to update a table similar to this

```
Table-Bill
item  cost  subtotal
itm1  1     1
itm2  5     6
itm3  4     10
itm4  3     13
```

My input is 'item' and 'cost' column, and trigger needs to update 'subtotal' with sum of all items inserted so far, I am not sure whether to use 'FOR EACH ROW' or for statement and then use cursor please help with solution with good performance

Comment: Unlike SQL Server, Postgres supports *row triggers*, there is no "inserted" table in a row trigger. What exactly are you trying to do? And another thing: you can **not** commit or rollback in a trigger function (or any function that is).

Comment: @safetyOtter "SQL" does not mean "Microsoft SQL Server". It is the *query language*. Don't assume that [tag:sql] means [tag:sql-server].

Comment: @safetyOtter: that is not a valid identifier in Postgres (or any ANSI standard compliant DBMS)

Comment: oops, wasn't reading carefully, ty for the correction

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You mean multiple rows cant be inserted at once if I dont use FOR EACH ROW pls see correction in code, I am actually inserting a row (only a few columns values) and want to update other columns based on inserted column values, for example if I am inserting two columns col1 and col2 with values 2 and 3 resp. trigger should update another column in same table say col_total with sum as 5 (2+3)

Comment: @safetyOtter actually in my previous question I used MSSQL but some one edited it as SQL SERVER, that is why I used it thinking that may be the proper term to used here

Comment: Of course you can insert multiple rows at once, but a trigger defined as "FOR EACH ROW" will be fired once for each row (a concept that does not exist in SQL Server). If you don't want that use a statement level trigger. But again: what are you actually trying to do here. Why not tell us the real problem, maybe your current solution is completely the wrong path.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i gave an example did you see? anyway I am looking to insert a table like below

Comment: edited in my question

Comment: What do you want to _do_ with the result of the `select count(*)` ? maybe "assign" it somehow ?

Comment: i can use cursor if its more than 1

Comment: Why do you want to store data that can be retrieved from the existing data with a simple select statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hey I am just showing very simplified example. in fact I am doing some arithmetic with inserted column values for each row and then update the other columns, based on inserted data some columns may be updated other may not, I hope this is clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FOR EACH STATEMENT does not support NEW and OLD usage so only way in current postgres is to go by FOR EACH ROW to access updated/inserted/deleted rows check this post for more information [How to use 'for statement' triggers in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600996/how-to-use-for-statement-triggers-in-postgres)