# How to use 'for statement' triggers in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

if we write a trigger FOR STATEMENT like below how can we access only updated rows in trigger procedure/function

```
CREATE FUNCTION func1()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    --access only updated/inserted rows here???
    RETURN null;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trig1
AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE OR INSERT
ON tbl1 FOR STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE func1();
```

I mean when there are multiple rows updated once like below

```
update tbl1 set col1=1 where col2 in (2,3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: I don't think you can. I think you need to use row triggers and go through `NEW` and `OLD`.

Comment: @mu is too short thanks for reply, I am using postgres 9.3, you mean it is not supported yet? there is no performance difference even if we use FOR EACH ROW for table updates of hundreds or thousands rows at once?

Comment: @RAFIQ There'd be a big performance difference if it was supported, but since PostgreSQL doesn't support `NEW` and `OLD` for `FOR EACH STATEMENT` triggers, `FOR EACH ROW` is your only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time there is no support for `NEW` and `OLD` pseudo-relations for `FOR EACH STATEMENT` triggers.

You must use `FOR EACH ROW` triggers.

In theory it's possible for PostgreSQL to have fake tables for the new- and old- row versions, connected together by some one-off generated key. Or a single table containing the new and old tuples as composite types. However, this is not currently supported, and as far as I know nobody is working on support for it.

For some applications it can be worth using `FOR EACH ROW` triggers to `INSERT` into a `TEMPORARY` table, then process the whole lot in a final `FOR EACH STATEMENT` trigger.

Comment: Thanks very much for clarification, i really wasted lot of time looking for help, now will move on with FOR EACH ROW triggers

Answer (score 8):

Now, it is possible to use an identifier for the table of inserted records in pg 10 :

```
CREATE TRIGGER transfer_insert
AFTER INSERT ON transfer
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS inserted
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_transfer_balances_to_zero();
```

Extracted from pg 10 doc : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createtrigger.html